# Flutter Problem in FireAuth Email Verification

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I tried to make email verification and the problem is that the app registered the user without sending the email

this is my Function code

```
Future<String> registerUsingEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    UserCredential userCredential = await firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    User user = userCredential.user;
    if(!user.emailVerified){
      await user.sendEmailVerification();
      print(user.email);
    }
    return user.uid;
  }
```

and this is my log

```
W/System  ( 3599): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/System  ( 3599): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/FirebaseAuth( 3599): Notifying id token listeners about user ( Q8d7R7mE9dOv5lAbkZH2UCiwmKA2 ).
D/FirebaseAuth( 3599): Notifying auth state listeners about user ( Q8d7R7mE9dOv5lAbkZH2UCiwmKA2 ).
W/System  ( 3599): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/flutter ( 3599): wasee.2132254@gmail.com
```

**EDIT**

**when I check my email I found the messages, so, wanna do something like waiting screen that waiting for the user verification and then resumes the registration process**

any idea?

Comment: editing my question

Comment: are you using FutureBuilder to render the waiting screen etc?

Comment: also, firebase_auth exposes a stream with the current authentication state, you can use stream builder to build it whenever its value changes

Comment: ill share some code that may help more

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: How to listen to the FirebaseUser is Email verified boolean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57192651/flutter-how-to-listen-to-the-firebaseuser-is-email-verified-boolean)

Comment: thx Frank , that's help me too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could check if Firebase `User user.isEmailVerified` is true