# How can you manually trigger onAuthStateChanged for Firebase Authentication in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have a an app built around a `StreamBuilder` listening for `FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged`

```
  return new StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
  stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
  builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) { ...
```

I'm trying to reload the user and use onAuthStateChanged to pick up when an email is verified.  User.reload() is insufficient with the `StreamBuilder`.  It's a similar issue to this [onAuthStateChanged doesn't get called when email is verified in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54591187/onauthstatechanged-doesnt-get-called-when-email-is-verified-in-flutter)

I thought a solution would be to force a logout and login but I'm at a loss on how to do that - e.g. step 2, login again to trigger onAuthStateChanged.

```
  _auth.signOut(); //sign out and immediate sign in
  final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signIn----( //which signin function?
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having the same issue in flutter

Comment: No. What I ended up doing was forcing the user to logout if he wasn't verified.  Then after he verifies he can login again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried refreshing auth token?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions

Answer (score 0):

Use _auth.userChanges() stream instead of _auth.onAuthStateChanges()

```
return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _auth.userChanges(),
      builder: (ctx, userSnapshot) {
        User? user = _auth.currentUser;
        if (userSnapshot.hasData && user != null && user.emailVerified) {
           // load screen on successful login
        }
        // fallback to auth screen
  },
);
```

and on successful verification call refreshToken in your verification method

```
Future<void> verifyEmail() async {
    user = _auth.currentUser;
    await user!.reload();
    if (user!.emailVerified) {
      setState(() {
        _isEmailBeingVerified = false;
      });
      user!.refreshToken;
    }
  }
```